# Python how to download protected files

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies

I would like to download a "token" protected file and to use my cookie file in order to avoid multiple re-login.
The way i proceed is as follow

First of all, import the cookie

```
import requests, cookielib

    cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
    cj.load()
    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
```

This is where i get a problem with, I must follow these steps in order to successfully download the desired file.
(Everything in square brackets have to be replaced)

```
>> http://videoXXXXXXXX.fr/index.php?optio … &video_id=[VIDEO_ID]&load=1
Recover the cookie provided via "header set-cookie" 
>> http://videoXXXXXXXX.fr/index.php?optio … &video_id=[VIDEO_ID]
Recover the "order_id" in the sent back page [ORDER_ID]
>> http://videoXXXXXXXX.fr/index.php?optio … &order_id=[ORDER_ID]
Recover the response token: [Token]
>> http://videoXXXXXXXX.fr/index.php?optio … raw&token=[Token]&order_id=[ORDER_ID]
This step allow the activation of the cookie recovered in step 1 as well as to obtain the complete file
>> http://videoXXXXXXXX.fr/picture_[VIDEO_ID].png
```

But the truth is, I would like some help in order to do all that in "Python"

Thank you in advance for your time, as well as your help.

Comment: Look into Mechanize http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569622/python-mechanize-following-link-by-url-and-what-is-the-nr-parameter

Comment: Np. Also, if you're just looking to get the IDs, use a parser like lxml or BeautifulSoup, they can help you extract the ORDER_ID and such from HTML easily

Comment: do you have an example to use BeautifulSoup or lxml ?

Comment: http://lxml.de/parsing.html and http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I looked the web site I don't know how to start I'm an inexperienced on this domaine

Comment: is possible to make this in bash script ?